# Source Control System for Pivotal CRM

Tags: version-control, pivotal-crm

We manage a multi-locale, multi-language Pivotal CRM System with developers spread across UK and India. We do not have any Source Control System to manage the development work. Is there any source control system that we can integrate with Pivotal CRM.

Note: "Please check with the providers CDC Software" is not a valid answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

I worked on Pivotal CRM for 6 years, and stopped asking CDC for source control. Their last response was that source control was a highly requested feature, but that they have no intent in making Pivotal CRM development work with any source control system.

I don't want to sound too jaded, but if you treat Pivotal CRM as a vertical solution that needs only the minimum of changes you will do well. If you are treating it as a framework to house lots of customizations/programming to implement unique business requirements, you will run into nothing but roadblocks and un-necessary challenges. Use SugarCRM, Microsoft Dynamics, or Salesforce.com instead.

Comment: Thanks! The last I heard was Pivotal CRM was including source control as part of the Toolkit itself with SP8, but then they scrapped it as some key developers quit CDC Software. We do use it as a vertical solution, but having a source control system is always beneficial no?

Comment: Source control is a good thing in most situations. The exception is when there is no one technical enough to understand it, and my feeling is that the non-techie crowd is the primary audience CDC seeks with their Pivotal CRM product.